# Javascript Async/Await timing

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a problem with async/await timing. I have this code:

```
async updateCreateDataGu(dataGu){
    let arraySaveOrUpdate = [];
    try {
        const dataAllGu = await DataService.getGeneratingUnits();
        Promise.all(dataGu.map( async itemGU => {
              let powerPlant = await powerPlantModel.findOne();
              // This one is being executed last
              console.log(powerPlant)
              console.log("I need this first")
              if(!itemGU.id){
                 let dataNew = { /*data*/ }
                 arraySaveOrUpdate.push(dataNew);

              } else {
                 let dataNew2 = { /*data*/ }
                 arraySaveOrUpdate.push(dataNew2);
              }
           }))
        // This one is being executed first
        console.log("here");
        // arraySaveOrUpdate is empty at this step
        if(arraySaveOrUpdate.length > 0){
          return await generatingUnitModel.bulkCreate(arraySaveOrUpdate);
        }else{
          return {};
        }
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
       throw new Error(error.message);
     }      
}
```

I don't know why is the `console.log("here")` executing first and not the `console.log("I need this first")` ?

Comment: As per Stack Overflow guidelines you should build a simplified example of your code.

Comment: You don't **`await`** `Promise.all`

Comment: [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns a promise. `await` that.

Comment: @Mark I did, the code is longer, that's why I put those "dummy" vars, and only `await` calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to await on `Promise.all`.

Replace

```
Promise.all(dataGu.map( async itemGU => {
```

by

```
await Promise.all(dataGu.map( async itemGU => {
```